# Adding a new entity to a ManyToOne association takes a lot of cpu power

Tags: postgresql, jpa, persistence

I am using eclipselink and postgresql in my jpa application.

I have 3 tables that are linked like that : Record @OneToMany to ArchiveMediasRecords, AchiveMedia @OneToMany to ArchiveMediasRecords, and ArchiveMediasRecords with @ManyToOne to both Record and AchiveMedia.

The ArchiveMediasRecords is a table that provides attribute information to the assocation between Record and AchiveMedia.

My problem, is that I am inserting a Record every 100 ms, and the insertion is done using a pool of 10 threads.

I am doing something like that :

Create new record
Create new entitymanager (one new em per thread execution)
Create a transaction, and start it
For each ArchiveMedia declared, do the assocation with Record via ArchiveMediasRecords
Persist the record (cascade is well declared to make it easier)
Commit the transaction

The database is updated, no problem there.

The problem, is that the number of records can big quite big (> 400000) but ArchiveMedia is not (< 20).

When I am adding the record to the archivemedia, the method add on the IndirectList of the @OneToMany association in ArchiveMedia takes a lot of time and a lot of cpu power.

Is there a way to reduce simple association process on big XXXToMany ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so because I wan't able to find how to optimize my massive insertion, I tryied something else :

I am inserting the record entity without the association. Then I am inserting the assocation by using low level jdbc from jpa.

It permits to lower to java process cpu load from 20% to 1% and lower the postgresql process cpu load from 18% to < 1%.

Great success !

But this is mainly a workaround than a real solution. Anyway, problem solved.